# Weighted Kirchhoff Matrix?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, matrix

I have a weighted graph and I want its graph Laplacian matrix (what Mathematica calls the Kirchhoff matrix in the unweighted case). Is there an easy way to get this?

For example, the command:

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[Graph[{0 \[UndirectedEdge] 1},EdgeWeight -> {3}]]//MatrixForm
```

returns the matrix

```
0   3
3   0
```

and

```
KirchhoffMatrix[Graph[{0 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, EdgeWeight -> {3}]] //MatrixForm
```

returns

```
1 -1
-1 1
```

whereas I would like

```
3 -3
-3 3
```

I can do it in an ugly way, but I am wondering if there is a beautiful way to do it.

---

#### Edit

I wrote a small function to do this, and it works.

```
     WeightedKirchhoffMatrix[G_] := 
    (M = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G];
     n = Length[M];
     e = Table[1, {i, n}];
     DiagonalMatrix[e.M] - M)
```

Comment: `WeightedKirchhoffMatrix[G_] := (DiagonalMatrix[Total[#, {1}]] - #) & [WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat shorter:

```
wKM[g_]:= DiagonalMatrix[Tr /@ Transpose@#] - # &@ WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g]
```

Comment: If the matrix is symmetrical, the Transpose part could be ommited